# Android Application multiple APKs on same device "...package conflicts with an existing package by the same name."

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play, android-manifest

I'm having a heck of a time getting a new build process for our Android Application to work. I'd like to have two different APKs that I can install side by side on the same device. However, I'm getting an error message that seems to be very common for people dealing with different APK configurations. The erorr message is as follows when I go to install the .release version the app after I've installed the .debug version -- "App not installed. The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name." Here is my build.gradle file for the application.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Properties props;
if (project.hasProperty("AndroidProject.signing")
    && new File(project.property("AndroidProject.signing")).exists()) {

props = new Properties()
props.load(new 
FileInputStream(file(project.property("AndroidProject.signing"))))
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 12
    versionName "2.4"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}
flavorDimensions "default"
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (props != null) {
            storeFile file(props['STORE_FILE'])
            storePassword props['STORE_PASSWORD']
            keyAlias props['KEY_ALIAS']
            keyPassword props['KEY_PASSWORD']
        } else {
            //Don't sign it with anything. APK will append "unsigned" to itself.
        }
    }
    debug {
        keyAlias 'debug'
        storeFile file('a file path not revealed')
        keyPassword 'debugandroid'
        storePassword 'debugandroid'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        if (props != null) {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debuggable false
        applicationIdSuffix ".release"
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}


dependencies {
//    implementation 'com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.2.0'
implementation 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.9'
implementation project(':lucityREST')
implementation project(':lucityCore')
implementation project(':lucityAndroidCore')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
}
```

A little bit of background on the project. This is a conversion from ANT to Gradle. The main application module that this build script is for sits on top of 3 smaller modules. Things I've tried to resolve the issue.

1. Completely different, explicit applicationIds for the release and debug versions.
2. Using productFlavors and trying different versionCodes, versionNames, applicationIds, etc.
3. Switching out keystores just to see if it's some sort of signing issue. Currently I have a debug signing that is not very important and uses a generated keystore through android studio. In addition I have the release keystore information in a .properties file maintained on a different machine and referenced outside the project (not checked into version control) for security purposes. These both build and the application works fine.
4. I've analyzed the both the .debug and .release APKs after they've been generated in Android Studio. The package names reflect the change using "applicationIdSuffix" in the build script.

I've also tried other small tweaks and ways of organizing the structure that I don't think are truly relevant to the discussion or would be to blame for the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this? Is it a possible side-effect of the migration from ANT? Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit 1:

Here is the result of running "appt dumb badging" on my debug apk. As you can see, the package name reflects that the .debug suffix has been added.

```
package: name='com.lucity.tablet2.debug' versionCode='12' versionName='2.4' platformBuildVersionName=''
sdkVersion:'15'
targetSdkVersion:'25'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
application-label:'Lucity 2.0 - QA'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-hdpi-v4/lucity_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi-v4/lucity_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/lucity_launcher.png'
application-icon-480:'res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/lucity_launcher.png'
application: label='Lucity 2.0 - QA' icon='res/drawable-hdpi-v4/lucity_launcher.png'
application-debuggable
launchable-activity: name='com.lucity.tablet2.ui.login2.ClientPickerActivity'  label='Lucity 2.0 - QA' icon=''
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' reason='requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
feature-group: label=''
  uses-gl-es: '0x20000'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.location'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.location.gps'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.location.network'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.wifi'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.landscape'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.landscape' reason='one or more activities have specified a landscape orientation'
main
other-activities
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '160' '240' '320' '480'
native-code: 'armeabi-v7a' 'x86'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, having eliminated the obvious answers, it is time to go digging around in the source code of android, which is all available at [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/).

I find this is easiest to do using a google search with prefix `site:android.googlesource.com`. So [searching for the error message](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Aandroid.googlesource.com+%22The+package+conflicts+with+an+existing+package+by+the+same+name.%22&oq=site%3Aandroid.googlesource.com+%22The+package+conflicts+with+an+existing+package+by+the+same+name.%22) we find this message has name `"install_failed_conflict"`. We want to find this in java files, so we search for ["install_failed_conflict" and java](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=zn-OWq7nLqmFgAaduqTgDA&q=site%3Aandroid.googlesource.com+%22install_failed_conflict%22+java&oq=site%3Aandroid.googlesource.com+%22install_failed_conflict%22+java) and find [InstallAppProgress](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+/90db305/src/com/android/packageinstaller/InstallAppProgress.java) gives this error whenever it gets `PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT`. We then search for [STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=2n-OWp-9D4z0gQb9jZHYAQ&q=site%3Aandroid.googlesource.com+%22STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT%22+java&oq=site%3Aandroid.googlesource.com+%22STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT%22+java) (this would be quicker if you had the android source in your IDE) and find that PackageManager actually uses [this code for lots of things](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r4/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#5541).

- Already exists (obviously), but also
- `INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE`
- `INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE`
- `INSTALL_FAILED_REPLACE_COULDNT_DELETE`
- `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER`
- `INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION`

I don't know exactly what all of these mean (but I could carry on looking in the source code to find out), but is it possible one of them applies to your APK? Maybe duplicate permission?

My top guess would be [this code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F#8351), I wonder if your debug package and your release package have conflicting providers?

Comment: Incredible advice. Let me get back to you after I look at this.

Comment: Just a follow up, I'm curious how this went

Comment: Still haven’t got to it yet! Hopefully will this week!

Comment: Nick - I still have yet to solve my issue, but I have an insight that might help narrow down what it could be. I recently upgraded the target and compile API level from 15 to 25. After doing this, I was never able to install two instances of the application with different applicationIDs on the same device. However, today I tried reverting back to API level 15, and I had no problems installing the two apks on the same device. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: Also, I went ahead and accepted your answer that references the source code even though it didn't directly solve my problem. I think it is helpful troubleshooting advice for anyone that encounters this issue.

Comment: The 15->25 change is super interesting. I don't know the change might be, but I'll look.

Comment: Mine was using a FileProvider with a hard-coded authority in the manifest.  This seems to be the `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` case

Answer (score 1):

An Android app is identified by a package name, eg `com.foo.bar`. You can only ever have one app with a given package name installed on a device at once. If you want your release and debug builds to both be installed on the same device, you will need to give them different package names, eg `com.foo.bar` and `com.foo.bar.debug`.

In gradle this is called the [applicationId](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).

It looks like the `applicationIdSuffix` setting in your gradle file is not having the correct effect.

If you use the aapt tool with the command line `aapt dump badging` on your APK you can see which package name is actually being written to your APK, and maybe see where the problem is, as it looks like the suffix isn't being used.

Comment: Hey, Nick. Thanks for the reply, but I've already analyzed the APKs and can confirm that my gradle file is applying the correct effect. I can see that the package names are correctly postfixed with .debug and .release, so I don't believe that this is the issue. I've checked this post build with the Android Studio tools. I understand that each application must have a unique applicationId.

Comment: Have you tried "adb shell pm list packages" on your device? That will tell you if you have an old version of the APK sitting around on the device blocking the install?

Comment: I checked what packages I had on the device using the "adb shell pm list packages", and there were no duplicates. I went ahead and removed my application from the tablet by uninstalling my application's package, rebooted my device, and tried again to install a release and debug version of the APK but to no avail.

I even went ahead and gave the package a different app_name JUST to see if that was the issue (even though I was positive it couldn't be). Still no dice. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Android is linux base system and every app is like new user and same application id is not permitted for different users. So to change id of same app like staging and production applications.
you can add build types in your gradle

```
android {                                                    
    buildTypes {
    release {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "is_prod", "true"
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App staging"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "is_prod", "false"
    }
  }                                                                      
}
```

than .debug will be added in package name.